# How to pass date value to directive without the double quotes?

Tags: date, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I create my directive, which passes a 'date variable' into it.

The thing is, the value obtained comes with a double quote (as in the image). 
If I pass a normal string, this doesn't happen.

How to modify it?

My original intention is to apply the filter straighforward inside the template. Such as:

```
<p> {{mdate | date: "MMM"}} </p>
```

but it seems not working and I have to use `link` function

**EDIT:**

This is how i call this directive:

```
 <dbd-custom-calendar mdate="{{dateLatest}}"></dbd-custom-calendar>
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Huh. Found that I should use `'='` instead of `'@'`!!!

[image]